# Algorithm for popular tables in PostgresQL

Tags: python, algorithm, postgresql

I'm writing an algorithm to populate all tables in a database in Postgres. I already get popular all tables **that have no relationship**, as follows:

1. I get all the tables with the following query:

   ```
   SELECT table_name
      FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND
      table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
   ```
2. For the list of tables obtained, I make a loop, and for each table I get its properties (column name, data type, accepts null or not, maximum characters):

   ```
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE,
      IS_NULLABLE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
   ```
3. With this list of properties I dynamically create the INSERT

   ```
   INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(prop1, prop2, prop3) VALUES(value1, value2, value3)
   ```

Each value is randomly generated based on the property type, eg:

- Integer: 65422
- Character: "Lorem ipsum..."
- Date: 2016-12-12 20:00

And so on for each data type accepted by the algorithm. If it finds some kind of data that is not accepted, the application terminates (which is expected).

4. And finally, with INSERT mounted I execute the query in the database

The steps in this algorithm work perfectly for tables where there **are no relationships**.

---

For tables that have relationships (1:N, 1:1, N:N), I would need to first find all the foreign keys and understand which tables they see, to enter the data in this table "Father" save the IDs and then insert In the "Daughters" tables thus associating their foreign keys. But how to do it in a simple way?

It is interesting to note that I can already get the list of all foreign keys through the following query:

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass AS table_from
      ,conname
      ,pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
FROM   pg_constraint c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
WHERE  contype IN ('f', 'p ')
AND    n.nspname = 'public' -- your schema here
ORDER  BY conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
```

I am grateful for suggestion.

**Note: The algorithm is being developed in Python.**

Answer (score 0):

Use CTEs:

```
WITH parents AS (
    INSERT INTO parent (parent_field)
    VALUES ('a'), ('b')
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO child (parent_id, child_field)
SELECT id, 'something' FROM parents;
```

That gets you one child per parent; if you want multiple children, cross join a `VALUES` list in the child insert like so:

```
INSERT INTO child (parent_id, child_field)
SELECT id, 'something'
FROM parents
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS multiplier;
```

Paired with the two-parent insert CTE, this generates two parents with three children each. Add more entries to the `VALUES` list to create more children for each parent; the content doesn't matter, just the quantity.